# Vue Handling Sidebar Navigation Loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm fairly new to Vue and Vuetify which I'm currently using to create a layout which consists of a side navigation menu on the left and a content loading area on the right. When you click on one of the menu items in the navigation area, it should load in a new vue component which contains the template for that particular layout in the content loading area (on the right of the menu). I've hacked together something that seems to be working... but I'm not sure if it's the "correct" way to go about doing this. Can anyone who is better at Vue and Vuetify let me know if this is the way I should go about this?
My page template looks like this:

```
<template>
    <v-layout class="fill-height">
        <v-navigation-drawer class="grey lighten-4">
            <v-list>
                <v-list-item-group v-model="selectedItem" color="primary">
                    <v-list-item
                        v-for="(item, i) in items"
                        :key="i"
                        @click="SelectMenuItem(item.title)"
                    >
                        <v-list-item-content>
                            <div class="font-weight-bold">
                                <v-list-item-title
                                    v-text="item.title"
                                ></v-list-item-title>
                            </div>
                        </v-list-item-content>
                    </v-list-item>
                </v-list-item-group>
            </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>
        <v-main>
            <v-container ref="container" fluid></v-container>
        </v-main>
    </v-layout>
</template>
```

And then my javascript section looks like this

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import AdminDocumentsEditor from '../components/AdminDocumentsEditor.vue';
import AdminPresetsEditor from '../components/AdminPresetsEditor.vue';

const AdminDocumentsEditorClass = Vue.extend(AdminDocumentsEditor);
const AdminDocumentsEditorInstance = new AdminDocumentsEditorClass();

const AdminPresetsEditorClass = Vue.extend(AdminPresetsEditor);
const AdminPresetsEditorInstance = new AdminPresetsEditorClass();

export default {
    name: 'AdminNav',
    components: {
        AdminDocumentsEditor,
        AdminPresetsEditor,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            selectedItem: 0,
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Documents',
                    icon: 'mdi-table-large-remove',
                    route: '/admindocumentseditor',
                },
                {
                    title: 'Presets',
                    icon: 'mdi-list-status',
                    route: '/adminpresets',
                },
            ],
        };
    },
    methods: {
        RemoveAllChildNodes(parent) {
            while (parent.firstChild) {
                parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);
            }
        },
        SelectMenuItem(item) {
            this.RemoveAllChildNodes(this.$refs.container);
            if (item === 'Documents') {
                AdminDocumentsEditorInstance.$mount();
                this.$refs.container.appendChild(
                    AdminDocumentsEditorInstance.$el
                );
            } else if (item === 'Presets') {
                AdminPresetsEditorInstance.$mount();
                this.$refs.container.appendChild(
                    AdminPresetsEditorInstance.$el
                );
            }
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

And finally my two component classes which get added/inserted are pretty basic at the moment. Eventually, these will be more complex, but right now they're just placeholders. But they look something like this:

```
<template>
    <div>Documents Editor</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'AdminDocumentsEditor',
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'correct' way (when you're making an SPA-like mini application like this), would be to use `vue-router` and their `<router-view>` component. This component automatically loads the component you specify in your route file depending on the active route, complete with handy lifecycle hooks to load/initialize data, or to cancel/redirect unauthorized routing before the route enters.

You can then also use the [`to` prop on `<v-list-item>`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-item/#props-to) to have it handle your navigation as links for vue-router.

Note: when your application has its own router (for example if you load Vue on a separate page in a rails app), make sure to let vue-router handle the sub-paths by passing every sub-path to the page that uses Vue.